# printThis script making chosen dropdowns appear black

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the jQuery scripts "printThis" for printing elements, and "Chosen" for dropdowns.

I get a problem with the chosen dropdowns coming out with a black background when using Chrome. No matter how I set the style for the element using background white or none I just can't seem to figure out why Chrome is making the dropdown have a black background when using printThis.

The following code is a quick sample on how to reproduce the issue:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen/chosen.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/printThis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dropdown").chosen();
        $("#printbutton").click(function() {
            $("#printarea").printThis();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="printarea">
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>Austria</option>
        <option>Belgium</option>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>Denmark</option>
        <option>Ecuador</option>
        <option>Finland</option>
        <option>Germany</option>
    </select>
    <input id="printbutton" type="button" value="Print">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to supply internet urls for the scripts but I cant find one for the printThis plugin, you can download it from the git hub website here:

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Comment: Hey Trant i am facing the same issue and was just wondering if you found out a work around this?

Comment: Interesting. I am the printThis author, and I have not seen this issue - I will take a look. Thanks.